# Syslog messages not being received at central server

Tags: linux, logging, centos7, syslog, rsyslog

I have a central Syslog server (Windows Server 2012 R2) running Kiwi Syslog server that isn't receiving logs from a client (Centos 7).

The client's rsyslog.conf configuration looks like this:

```
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure
# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog
# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron
# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*
# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler
# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log

# ### begin forwarding rule ###
# Remote Logging (we use TCP for reliable delivery)
#
#$ActionQueueFileName fwdRule1 # unique name prefix for spool files
#$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g   # 1gb space limit (use as much as possible)
#$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save messages to disk on shutdown
#$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # run asynchronously
#$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries if host is down
# remote host is: name/ip:port, e.g. 192.168.0.1:514, port optional
*.*  @@cloudDC:514
```

Where cloudDC is the name of the logging server.

I have verified:

- logs are being printed to /var/log/messages
- TCP and UDP 514 are open on server
- Server can display logs from localhost
- Client and server can reach each other

I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Start by running tcpdump on both boxes and see if a session is actually started and go from there.